# How to create inject React components from XML

Tags: javascript, xml, reactjs

Imagine you made a web framework that helps you quickly make blogs for clients. For the sake of this post, its the same blog template everytime, what changes is the content. You're React app is a simple structure of the following [where the Content state is just changing each time]

```
<App>
  <Navigation/>
  <Content/>
</App>
```

What makes the framework is you have XML files which contain the HTML. Each XML file represents one blog post. The app pulls all the HTML from the XML files, and puts it into the state of the App in a "blog posts" array. Depending on the state of the app, a specific entry in the array will be displayed in Content...

Content's state has a field called "html" which is what holds the HTML to be injected in string form. [you have to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML]

---

This concept works fine, and I have a version of it now. However, imagine you have a React components that you want to add to each blog post. Say you want to add the  component into a specific blog post in a specific section. You want to add props to it and such. Now this goes out the window with dangerouslySetInnerHTML

This is where I am stuck trying to find the best direction to go. The only thought I have now is the following:

> Since you would now be writing JSX in the XML, just make each blog post its own component. You would have   ...etc and then if this.state.currentPost === 1 then display BlogPost1 and likewise. Yet you would have to have a huge block of if-statements depending on how many blogposts you have, and its not ideal to have to add everytime you have a new blogpost

Answer (score 1):

When I read the title of your question I got curious and found this library to parse XML into React components: [xml-to-react](https://github.com/CondeNast/xml-to-react). But that's not what you are asking for.

As you want to use components in the middle of you string of HTML, I'll suggest: [react-remarkable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-remarkable). This component compiles its children (a string with markdown/html/react) into react nodes.

Example from its docs:

```
 var React = require('react');
 var Markdown = require('react-remarkable');

 var MyComponent = React.createClass({

   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         {/* Pass Markdown source to the `source` prop */}
         <Markdown source="**Markdown is awesome!**" />

         {/* Or pass it as children */}
         {/* You can nest React components, too */}
         <Markdown>{`
           ## Reasons React is great

           1. Server-side rendering
           2. This totally works:

           <SomeOtherAmazingComponent />

           Pretty neat!
         `}</Markdown>
       </div>
     );
   }

 });
```